# React-Hooks : Listen to Events across independent Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, react-hooks

My App has following sample structure:

```
<App>
--<Users>
------<UserList/>
--</Users>
--<UserManagement>
------<UserList/>
------<AddUser/>
--</UserManagement>
</App>
```

In `<UserManagement>` I use a state variable to listen to the mutation that gets done in `<AddUser>` so that the `<UserList>` directly updates after the mutation has been done.

Now if I add a user and go to , the `<UserList>` there does not re-render as it has no idea about the change in the database. I don't know on what for example a useEffect hook should listen to.

I thought about using React Context provided in `<App>`. But I'm not sure if this is the right solution. I'm using a simple sqlite database not providing any subscription tools or sth.

Can anybody provide me a hint?

I hope its understandable with this, otherwise I will provide code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

1. you can pass the same state variable in  to the  component that signifies a change in user list. use the useEffect hook to listen for this variable to get the user list again from the database.
2. create another state variable in  that basically sync up with your database. You pass this variable into the  component. when the user is added, you add to the sql database and this variable. You also pass this same variable into  to display the users. Keep in mind that this approach basically makes a copy of the user list.